# Editext inputType="textCapCharacters" not working on Android 4.0+?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Editext `inputType="textCapCharacters"` seems to be working on Android 2.3 (opens keyboard with capitalized letters by default) but does not do that on 4.0. Am I missing something or is this part of API deprecated (couldn't find any reference to that) ?

Comment: same problem here. Have you solved this? I guess it works only with the stock keyboard...

Answer (score 2):

I guess it works only with the stock keyboard, custom keyboards override those settings. I tested it on Android 4.0 and it was working only with the stock keyboard, not with third party ones.